# Installed Ubuntu-Tweak but there's no icon

Tags: package-management, ubuntu-tweak

I installed [Ubuntu Tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/), but I don't see an icon. 
Am I supposed to have a Tweak icon somewhere?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ubuntu Tweak is in `Applications>System Tools`

From Unity, press the Super or Windows key, then type "tweak" to display it.